# Can't understand an Oracle group by result involving count(distinct col)

Tags: sql, oracle

When I execute a simple oracle SQL query with `count(distinct column x)` it gives me some number and when executing with grouping by another column it gives a greater number. How come?

```
SELECT                                                distinct branch_no,
      COUNT (DISTINCT member_no)
  FROM subscriptions                                       
 WHERE       
           su_sub_status NOT IN ('N', 'C')
       AND TRUNC (sub_Date) <= TO_DATE ('31/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
       AND TRUNC (end_date) >= TO_DATE ('31/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

group by /* rollup */ (branch_no)
```

This is the other one with no group by

```
    SELECT                                   --             distinct branch_no,
      COUNT (DISTINCT member_no)
  FROM subscriptions                                       
 WHERE       
           su_sub_status NOT IN ('N', 'C')
       AND TRUNC (sub_Date) <= TO_DATE ('31/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
       AND TRUNC (end_date) >= TO_DATE ('31/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

--group by /* rollup */ (branch_no)
```

Answer (score 4):

For this sample data:

```
grp1   grp2   value
1      1      1
2      1      1
3      2      2
```

If you group by `grp1`, there will be three groups, each with one `count(distinct value)`.  For a total of 3.

If you group by `grp2`, the first group (with `grp2 = 1`) will have a `count(distinct value)` of one.  The second group (with `grp2 = 2`) will also have a `count(distinct value)` of one.  This sums up to 2.

As you can see, there is nothing inconsistent about different groups having a different sum of `count(distinct value)`.